# How to change numeric validation to string validation

Tags: javascript

Currently I have a validation where I disable the buttons depending on the numerical value as follows:

```
disabled = [0,2,3,5]

/* Formatting function for row details - modify as you need */
function format(d) {
    // `d` is the original data object for the row
    $tipoproveedor = $("#txttipoproveedor").val();
    console.log(d);
    let tabla = `<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 40px 5px;">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                Date Order
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Order
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Status
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>`;
                                                        
     d.Factura.forEach(f => { tabla += 
                               `<tr>                                                         
                                <td>${f.DateInvoice}</td>
                                <td>${f.Invoice}</td>       
                                <td>${f.Status}</td>                                                                                           
                                <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalCargaFactura" onclick="LoadInvoice('${f.PurchaseOrder}' )"`;
                 
                                if($tipoproveedor != '0'){
                                    if (disabled.indexOf(f.Estatus) > -1) {
                                        tabla += ` disabled `;
                                    }
                                }    
                                tabla += `>Upload Documents</button></td>                               
                                <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="ShowDetailsInvoice('${f.Invoice}')">Details</button></td>
                                </tr>`;
     });
     tabla += '</tbody></table>';
     return tabla;    
}
```

Where I disable the button in the values `0,2,3,5` now these values ​​will change to strings giving the following assignment to the numeric values ​​like this:

```
0 = 'None'
2 = 'Accept'
3 = 'Send'
5 = 'Delivered'
```

What I require now is to validate no longer with the numbers but with the character string, I hope someone can give me some guidance with this validation.

**Update 1:**

Based on the answer I have made the following code changing my array of values ​​for strings as follows:

```
disabled = ['None','Accept','Send','Delivered']
    
    /* Formatting function for row details - modify as you need */
    function format(d) {
        // `d` is the original data object for the row
        $tipoproveedor = $("#txttipoproveedor").val();
        console.log(d);
        let tabla = `<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 40px 5px;">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>
                                    Date Order
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Order
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Status
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>`;
                                                            
      d.Factura.forEach(f => {tabla += 
                                   `<tr>                                                         
                                    <td>${f.DateInvoice}</td>
                                    <td>${f.Invoice}</td>       
                                    <td>${f.Status}</td>                                                                                           
                                    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalCargaFactura" onclick="LoadInvoice('${f.PurchaseOrder}' )"`;
                     
                                    if($tipoproveedor != '0'){
                                        if (disabled.indexOf(f.Estatus) > -1) {
                                        tabla += ` disabled `;
                                        }
                                    }    
                                    tabla += `>Upload Documents</button></td>                               
                                    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="ShowDetailsInvoice('${f.Invoice}')">Details</button></td>
                                    </tr>`;
      });
      tabla += '</tbody></table>';
      return tabla;    
    }
```

What little I understand is that the validation no longer detects the numerical values ​​that existed in the array `disabled` and for this reason it marks the error and the data is not loaded into the table.

It will explain a little more in detail, currently I have in the table the column `Status` where the values ​​are shown `0,2,3,5` and the buttons are disabled or enabled depending on their value. In this case I have been forced to change these same values ​​for strings and in order not to complicate my life much I have decided to make this change from the query with which I show the data in the table with its simple caselike this:

```
CASE STATUS
                WHEN 0 THEN 'None'
                WHEN 1 THEN 'Receipment'
                WHEN 2 THEN 'Accept'
                WHEN 3 THEN 'Send'
                WHEN 4 THEN 'Process'
                WHEN 5 THEN 'Delivered'
                ELSE 'Other'
            END as 'STATUS'
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused at this point. If your query is returning the string values, why can't you just check if the item status is any of the four strings you want to disable? Can you elaborate on how both the numeric values and string values are to be used?

Comment: @MattU It is that this is how I really require it, what I need to validate is that if the state of the element is any of the four strings that you want to disable, but this validation `(disabled.indexOf (f.Estatus)> -1) {table + = `disabled`; }` It would no longer work for me in the case of doing it with strings

Comment: Then there should be nothing wrong with the one answer where you have the array of strings and then check if `f.Estatus` is in that array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the values as an object in the form:

```
const disabledValues = {
    0: 'None',
    2: 'Accept',
    3: 'Send',
    5: 'Delivered',
};
```

Later, during a comparison, **cast your `Estatus` into the number** (adding `+` at the beginning) and use it in the form:

```
if (disabledValues[+f.Estatus]) {
    tabla += ` disabled `;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but it sounds like you now expect `.Estatus` to contain a string instead of a number, and you still want the button disabling to work?  If that's the case just change

```
disabled = [0,2,3,5]
```

to

```
disabled = ['None', 'Accept', 'Send', 'Delivered']
```

or even

```
disabled = [0, 2, 3, 5, 'None', 'Accept', 'Send', 'Delivered']
```

so you can handle both.

```js
disabled = [0, 2, 3, 5, 'None', 'Accept', 'Send', 'Delivered']

/* Formatting function for row details - modify as you need */
function format(d) {
    // `d` is the original data object for the row
    $tipoproveedor = $("#txttipoproveedor").val();
    console.log(d);
      let tabla = `<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 40px 5px;">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                Date Order
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Order
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Status
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>`;
                                                        
                            d.Factura.forEach(f => {                            
                                tabla += `<tr>                                                         
                                <td>${f.DateInvoice}</td>
                                <td>${f.Invoice}</td>       
                                <td>${f.Status}</td>                                                                                           
                                <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalCargaFactura" onclick="LoadInvoice('${f.PurchaseOrder}' )"`;
                 
                                if($tipoproveedor != '0'){
                                    if (disabled.indexOf(f.Estatus) > -1) {
                                        tabla += ` disabled `;
                                    }
                                }    
                                  tabla += `>Upload Documents</button></td>                               
                                <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="ShowDetailsInvoice('${f.Invoice}')">Details</button></td>
                                </tr>`;
                            });
                       tabla += '</tbody></table>';
                       return tabla;    
}
```

Comment: If I want to change it to `disabled = ['None', 'Accept', 'Send', 'Delivered']` I will not have a way for the validation of deactivating the button to be fulfilled since I do this validation with the numerical values, How can I validate it with strings?

Comment: I'm a little bit confuse! What do you mean by validate with strings? so the now disabled = ["0", "2", "3", "5"] ?

Answer (score 0):

Initialise you array like below, where you can customize your message.

```
const valuesToDisable = [
    {
        value: 0,
        note: 'None'
    },
    {
        value: 2,
        note: 'Accept'
    },
    {
        value: 3,
        note: 'Send'
    },
    {
        value: 5,
        note: 'Delivered'
    }
]
```

Iterate through the array and display it's note accordingly.

Comment: It is possible that you can adapt the answer to my code to give it validity ?

Answer (score 0):

First, define your statuses in an object, give them a value how a button is disabled:

```
const statuses = {
  None: true,
  Receipment: false,
  Accept: true,
  Send: true,
  Process: true,
  Delivered: true,
  Other: false,
};
```

Then tune your code as:

```
if ($tipoproveedor != '0') {
  if (statuses[f.Estatus]) {
    tabla += ` disabled `;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick idea, can be optimised further:

Your array :

```
const disabled = [
    {
        id: 0,
        text: 'None'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        text: 'Accept'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        text: 'Send'
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        text: 'Delivered'
    }
];
```

A function to determinate the status

```
isButtonDisabled = function(status) {

    const found = disabled.filter(d => { 
                      return d.text === status; 
                  });

    return found.length ? true : false
}
```

Usage:

```
if ($tipoproveedor != '0'){
    if (isButtonDisabled(f.Estatus)) { 
        tabla += ` disabled `; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading the question and all the answers I failed to understand why it's not working.

By saying "I have been forced to change these same values ​​for strings" if the questioner means,
now the array  disabled = [ "0", "2", "3", "5" ]
and typeof f.Estatus === "string" then the solution is obvious.

```js
const disabled = [ "0", "2", "3", "5" ]

if(disabled.includes(f.Estatus))
  tabla += "disabled"
```